# GridView SelectRow function effect is not visible

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress, gridcontrol

I am trying to make all rows of my gridView selected (in constructor of WinForms window) with the following piece of code:

```
        gridControl1.DataSource = myObj;
        gridControl1.ForceInitialize();

        for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.DataRowCount; i++)
        {
            if (((MyClass)gridView1.GetRow(i)).MyProperty)
                gridView1.SelectRow(i);
        }
```

In debug, I checked that `gridView1.IsRowSelected()` returns true for all rows (after form is loaded). However, it is not displayed (the checkboxes are not checked). What am I doing wrong? I tried executing this code on form loading, but it didn't help.

Comment: Keep in mind that _selected_ doesn't equal _checked_. That means, a row can be selected, while not being checked. Selected normally means that the row is _highlighted_ (as if you single click on it), while checked means, that the checkbox is ticked (as if you click on the checkbox).

Answer (score 1):

> **ColumnViewOptionsSelection.MultiSelect** property is set to true.

```
        try
        {
            gridView1.BeginUpdate();
            for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.DataRowCount; i++)
            {
                var rowhandle = gridView1.GetRowHandle(i);
                if (((MyClass)gridView1.GetRow(rowhandle)).MyProperty)
                    gridView1.SelectRow(rowhandle);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            gridView1.EndUpdate();
        }
```

DataRowIndex and Rowhandle are different in devexpress.